# SQL How to find out what tables have a certain column

Tags: pervasive-sql

Is it possible to construct a query so that I can find out what tables have a particular column? Then if it has the column query that table for an ID number? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I think you can look at the contents of the X$Field system table, described here:
http://ww1.pervasive.com/library/docs/psql/794/sqlref/sqlsystb.html